# Import/Restore MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 different dumps from a prev setup(MySQL 5.xx). The first one is a self-contained file on about 250 MB, the other is a folder with 317 SQL files. Both is dumps from the same setup, just in different formats.

Now I need to restore one of them in the new MySQL 8 setup.

The folder dump contains a total of 10 schemas including sys. The MySQL 8 is just created so there is only a sys schema.

When I run the Import I just get a lot of errors like this:

> 10:09:24 Restoring myvideos93 (streamdetails) Running: mysql.exe
>   --defaults-file="c:\users\jimmy\appdata\local\temp\tmpk7oihn.cnf"  --protocol=tcp --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments --database=myvideos93 < "F:\20180605
>   Backup\Documents\dumps\Dump20180605\myvideos93_streamdetails.sql"
>   ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'myvideos93'
>
> Operation failed with exitcode 1

I'm doing this from MySQL Workbench on Windows 10 x64.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I hade to create each schema manually, but that was not enouth. I also hade to run the import 3 times until I only got 1 minor error. MySQL Windows components are still surprisingly unstable.